# Windows AD to OpenLDAP synchronisation with password cache

Tags: windows, active-directory, openldap, synchronization

We're looking for an "LDAP proxy" solution that can synchronize a Windows Active Directory with an OpenLDAP server **inclusive passwords**.

The openLDAP server will act as primary and failover for authentication if the Windows AD server is offline.

Could you help us with this?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

John